# Closer Look at HTML5 Canvas fillStyle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[JSFiddle Link (But, please read first)](http://jsfiddle.net/2fv0b7yd/)

Let us say, I have a canvas of `400 x 200`

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

I added a ball of `40 x 40` to the canvas: (see the function below)

```
createdBall(20,20,20)
```

In this function, the center of the ball is at 20px from top, left and has a radius of 20px. (Same Dimensions as original image used)

```
function createBall(x,y,r){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    context.fill();

}
```

The result is:
[image]

Now, I add some more balls: **The fillStyle is screwed up.**

```
createBall(50,50,20);
createBall(80,80,20);
```

[image]

I found out that what happens that the whole canvas get filled for a second like this and only a part we want to fill is picked. Something like this:
[image]

This is what exactly happening with my balls. How do I fill my each Ball with an Image?

Comment: I do not know the answer. But I like your explanation. Good Question and hard work before asking!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of arc's x-y you can use transform/translate, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fv0b7yd/4/):

```
createBall(20, 20, 20);
createBall(50, 50, 20);
createBall(80, 80, 20);

function createBall(x,y,r){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.beginPath();
    context.translate(x - r, y - r);
    context.arc(r, r, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    context.fill();
    context.translate(-(x - r), -(y - r));
}
```

> ...and this works because... translate(x,y) is actually pushing the
>   canvas's [0,0] origin rightward and downward to [x,y]. This also
>   pushes the image-pattern from left-top to [x,y] so that it now nicely
>   fits inside the arc. BTW, it's more efficient to create the pattern
>   once outside the createBall function. ;-) — @markE

Comment: Can you do the trouble of explaining? And posting code if possible

Comment: @K3N the additional calculations are required for this specific question.